# if else condition in java, android

Tags: java, android

i have a TextView which is set using...

```
// Declare view variables
private TextView mInfoText;

// Assign views from layout file to cor. vars
mInfoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoText);
```

how do i do an if else statement for the text inside it, i thought about doing it like this, but it doesn't work, i get a red line under the word "Sand".

```
if (mInfoText = "Sand"){

                //Show correct

            } else {

                //Show incorrect
            }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `mInfoText` is a `View`. The view is drawn on your screen. So, you cannot compare a `View` and a `String`. You should get content of the view. Use `mInfoText.getText()`, which will return `String`

Comment: Hint: `TextUtils.equals`

Answer (score 2):

You are wanting to compare the value of a `TextView` to a String. A TextView is not a String, not exacty. Its an object with properties. You need to call `getText()` to return a String.

Furthermore, you need to use `==`, which is an equality check. This will return true or false on the statement. If you use one `=` it will always be true. One equal sign is used for assignment

```
if (mInfoText.getText() == "Sand")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
if (mInfoText.getText().equals("Sand")){
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do like this.As String Objects should be compared using `String#equals` method.

```
if (mInfoText!=null && mInfoText.getText().toString().equals("Sand")){

      //Show correct

} else {

     //Show incorrect
}
```

Comment: look closer. `mInfoText` is not a `String`

Comment: You'll need to getText and toString on the View first

Comment: My bad. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: equals checks for null first, so need to check it before equals...

Answer (score 0):

You neded to get the content of the text field using `mInfoText.getText()`
and then compare it usgin `equals`

```
if(mInfoText != null && mInfoText.getText().equals("Sand")){
    //Show correct
}else{
    //Show incorrect
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`=` is assignment operator. Use `==` operator to do comparision of instance.

You should use `equals()` method to check if contents of two strings are the same.

Comment: not expecting this answer from you as you have that much reputation. Please see question carefully and then post the answer. Author trying to compare string with TextView instance.